# Getting error while writing test cases for amazonSNS.publish()

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, amazon-sns, mockk

**Src Code**

```
class ReportingUtil {
    companion object {
        private val gson = Gson()
        private val amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().build()
        private val topicArn = AppConfig.findString(TOPIC_ARN)
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert object to json format and will publish to SNS topic.
     * [invoiceData] -
     */
    fun publishFailureInvoiceToSNS(invoiceData: InvoiceData) {
        val jsonInvoiceMap = gson.toJson(invoiceData)
        log.info("The Invoice : $invoiceData is converted to json format : $jsonInvoiceMap")
        amazonSNS.publish(topicArn, jsonInvoiceMap)
        log.info("Json invoice: $jsonInvoiceMap is published to the sns topic")
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
@Test
fun `test to publish invoice data to SNS topic`(){
    initConfig()
    val amazonSNS = mockk<AmazonSNS>()
    val invoiceData = InvoiceData("a", "a", "a", BigDecimal(6), "a", "a", mutableMapOf("a" to "a"))
    val reportingUtil = ReportingUtil()
    every { 
            amazonSNS.publish("topicArn", "jsonInvoiceMap") 
   } returns PublishResult().withMessageId("MESSAGE_ID")
    reportingUtil.publishFailureInvoiceToSNS(invoiceData)
}
```

**This is giving me following error on src publish line,**

> com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid
> parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required
> parameter (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> InvalidParameter; Request ID: 5f1732ac-d63e-5e13-964c-65c312e218d7;
> Proxy: null)

My use-case does not allow me to use dependency injection, therefore I made client static here.

I also want to add my custom optimization plans in catalyst which will also be triggered at build time. Is there any way to do all this before execution?

Answer (score 1):

The `amazonSNS` you have mocked is not the one used to publish data in `publishFailureInvoiceToSNS` is not the one. So, when you call `publishFailureInvoiceToSNS` you are actually calling the real SNS API.

You have to refactor your code to use some kind of dependency injection. At least you should make it configurable. There are no use-cases that "does not allow to use DI".

If you're using JUnit 5, you could use [these helpers](https://madhead.me/posts/aws-junit5/) for AWS clients injections in test. I would also recommend using [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) for unit tests.

Comment: Okay but due to some reason...I am not allowed to use DI here. how can I mock it in that case?

Comment: Name the reason?

Comment: this is basically a utility pakcage...this package will be integrated by many of my clients. these clients uses spring, guice, dagger frameworks etc so there will be problem if i use any one of these frameworks

Comment: So it's just their responsibility to provide a client. Look, you're using `AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard().build()`. But what if your clients need to change the region? They should be able to configure the client.